# What's wrong with this server config for Wordpress (nginx, varnish, apc)?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi, varnish

I’m setting up the Wordpress backend for a high traffic website (gets around 15-20 million pageviews a month). It's up ad running but it's not performing as I wished.

The components are:

1. Php5-fpm
2. FastCGI
3. Nginx
4. Varnish
5. APC
6. W3TC
7. Cloudflare (Business Plan)
8. Hosting on Digitalocean (32 GB Memory, 12 Core processor, 320 GB SSD Disk)

I’m not an expert but I’ve set up everything taking help of online blogs and documentation. But I’m sure something is amiss as sometimes I get errors like “**Error connecting to database**”, **slow speed when opening the website for the first time** (long wait time when checked with pingdom tools)

So sharing the config so that the experts here can comment on the server settings. Am I missing anything?

Please note: There are other params too in the below files, I’ve noted down the most relevant

**PHP settings:**

/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 5000
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 10M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 10M
max_file_uploads = 20
default_socket_timeout = 90
mysql.connect_timeout = 3000
session.cache_expire = 180
[apc]
apc.write_lock = 1
apc.slam_defense = 0
apc.shm_size = "1024M"
```

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen = /dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 25
pm.min_spare_servers = 25
pm.max_spare_servers = 50
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60s;
pm.max_requests = 2000
request_terminate_timeout = 600
php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = 0
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 1G
```

**Nginx:**

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  24;
worker_rlimit_nofile 200000;
events {
    worker_connections  4000;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}
http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_header_timeout 240;
    client_body_timeout 240;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    client_max_body_size 32m;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    port_in_redirect off;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
client_max_body_size 10M;
listen 8080;
set $cache_uri $request_uri;

        # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
        if ($request_method = POST) {
                set $cache_uri 'null cache';
        }
        if ($query_string != "") {
                set $cache_uri 'null cache';
        }

        # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
        if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
                set $cache_uri 'null cache';
        }

        # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
        if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
                set $cache_uri 'null cache';
        }

        # Use cached or actual file if they exists, otherwise pass request to WordPress
        location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }
location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;

        }

        # BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
        location ~ \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
    expires 31536000s;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1";
}
location ~ \.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
    expires 3600s;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public";
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1";
}
location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
    expires 31536000s;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.4.1";
}
# END W3TC Browser Cache
}
```

**Varnish:**

I’ve taken the VCL files from Dreamhost’s VCL collection: https://github.com/dreamhost/varnish-vcl-collection

/etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend default {
        .host = "127.0.0.1";
        .port = "8080";
}

import std;

include "lib/xforward.vcl";
include "lib/cloudflare.vcl";
include "lib/purge.vcl";
include "lib/bigfiles.vcl";        # Varnish 3.0.3+
#include "lib/bigfiles_pipe.vcl";  # Varnish 3.0.2
include "lib/static.vcl";

acl cloudflare {
        # set this ip to your Railgun IP (if applicable)
        # "1.2.3.4";
}

acl purge {
        "localhost";
        "127.0.0.1";
}

# Pick just one of the following:
# (or don't use either of these if your application is "adaptive")
# include "lib/mobile_cache.vcl";
# include "lib/mobile_pass.vcl";
### WordPress-specific config ###
# This config was initially derived from the work of Donncha Ó Caoimh:
# http://ocaoimh.ie/2011/08/09/speed-up-wordpress-with-apache-and-varnish/
sub vcl_recv {
        # pipe on weird http methods
        if (req.request !~ "^GET|HEAD|PUT|POST|TRACE|OPTIONS|DELETE$") {
                return(pipe);
        }

        ### Check for reasons to bypass the cache!
        # never cache anything except GET/HEAD
        if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
                return(pass);
        }
        # don't cache logged-in users or authors
        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wp-postpass_|wordpress_logged_in_|comment_author|PHPSESSID") {
                return(pass);
        }
        # don't cache ajax requests
        if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
                return(pass);
        }
        # don't cache these special pages
        if (req.url ~ "nocache|wp-admin|wp-(comments-post|login|activate|mail)\.php|bb-admin|server-status|control\.php|bb-login\.php|bb-reset-password\.php|register\.php") {
                return(pass);
        }

        ### looks like we might actually cache it!
        # fix up the request
        set req.grace = 2m;
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?replytocom=.*$", "");

        # Remove has_js, Google Analytics __*, and wooTracker cookies.
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(__[a-z]+|has_js|wooTracker)=[^;]*", "");
        set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");
        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
                unset req.http.Cookie;
        }

        return(lookup);
}

sub vcl_hash {
        # Add the browser cookie only if a WordPress cookie found.
        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wp-postpass_|wordpress_logged_in_|comment_author|PHPSESSID") {
                hash_data(req.http.Cookie);
        }
}
sub vcl_fetch {
        # make sure grace is at least 2 minutes
        if (beresp.grace < 2m) {
                set beresp.grace = 2m;
        }

        # catch obvious reasons we can't cache
        if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie) {
                set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        }

        # Varnish determined the object was not cacheable
        if (beresp.ttl <= 0s) {
                set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Not Cacheable";
                return(hit_for_pass);

        # You don't wish to cache content for logged in users
        } else if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wp-postpass_|wordpress_logged_in_|comment_author|PHPSESSID") {
                set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Got Session";
                return(hit_for_pass);

        # You are respecting the Cache-Control=private header from the backend
        } else if (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
                set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO:Cache-Control=private";
                return(hit_for_pass);

        # You are extending the lifetime of the object artificially
        } else if (beresp.ttl < 300s) {
                set beresp.ttl   = 300s;
                set beresp.grace = 300s;
                set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES:Forced";

        # Varnish determined the object was cacheable
        } else {
                set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
        }
  # Avoid caching error responses
        if (beresp.status == 404 || beresp.status >= 500) {
                set beresp.ttl   = 0s;
                set beresp.grace = 15s;
        }

        # Deliver the content
        return(deliver);
}
```

**Wordpress**
wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );
```

**On W3TC, I’ve the following turned on:**

```
Page Cache (APC)
Database Cache (APC)
Object Cache (APC)
Browser cache
```

**Cloudflare settings:**

```
Minify: Off
Rocket Loader: Off
Caching level: Standard
```

Kindly guide me. Kindly suggest better settings, if any.

Comment: could you run a plugin like `debug bar` to check how many db queries are run per page load, especially when generating cache or uncached endpoints and report back.

Comment: Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: On homepage, it says: Total Queries:132
Total query time:244.5 ms

Comment: is homepage cached? if not then with the amount of traffic you get 132 queries per request may be the reason your db service keeps dying and slow page load times could be due to locked db rows (depending on what the queries are).

Comment: Yes, the homepage is cached using APC. Also, database cache is also enabled on APC.

Comment: I don't understand, after so many levels of caching server-size (nginx, varnish, apc) and browser side and cloudflare, why is it still slow. Is there something wrong in my server side setting?

Comment: well slow speed when opening for the first time could be related to many things, including dns latency, large browser uncached assets, etc. 
I'm assuming the db is on the same instance, and so db dying issues is likely related to high number of concurrent queries and/or lack of memory (as it will be shared by APC, nginx, etc). So, are 132 queries run even if homepage is cached? How often is the content updated? Does content on homepage vary by time/is randomised?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108257/discussion-between-littlelebowski-and-mani).